# Using a div inplace of a check box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a check list page which contains an unordered list of divs. When a div is clicked, jquery toggles a class of "selected". When submitted, jquery makes an array of all "selected" ids and passes it via AJAX to the server.

Is this proper? Am I breaking rules? I seems to work fine. I've seen examples of formatted check boxes, but this method is cleaner and easier. Possibly too easy which is why I'm asking you fine group of people for help. Thank you.

Comment: It's fine to do that, I don't see any problems.

Comment: Totally fine, and sometimes useful. For fun, try changing the class of 10,000 divs and compare that the performance of changing 10,000 checkboxes.

Comment: I like this idea. Could come in handy for our designers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not "proper" because it ignores the semantics of HTML.

If you're concerned about accessibility, you should use checkboxes and `<labels>` so assistive technology like screen readers will know what to do. And of course, the app won't work at all without JavaScript enabled.

You should be able to use CSS and JavaScript to make the page look and feel exactly the way you want while still using checkboxes. It's obviously more work, and it's up to you to decide if the benefit justifies the cost.

Comment: +1 at the very least, make sure the div can be focused with the keyboard (you'll need to add `tabindex="0"`) and handles keyboard events. Also make sure there's some text in the div that makes the operation obvious for a screenreader user.